# output xml fragment without headers

Tags: php, xml, doctype

I have a feeling I'm being thick, but here's my problem:

I'm creating dynamic XML trees using PHP.  These trees describe employee hierarchies, file directories, etc.  They comprise small sections of content on a webpage.  The rest of the webpage is glued together from various other sources that may be SQL based, or static text or some special presentation class.  When I go to output my trees, I transform the XML into a nested `<ul>`.  I'd like to output that `<ul>` without any doctype/header info.  PHP's DomDocument and SimpleXML classes don't seem to allow this.  Is the only option to strip the offending info off after storing the `<ul>` in a string?

Comment: That's a problem I'd like to have!

Comment: Ha. Very Ha.  Not only am I thick, my fingers don't obey me! Dratted submit buttons.

Comment: You transform the xml into a nested [what]?

Comment: Sorry about that. I didn't quote the `<ul>`. Fixed now.

Comment: People slow down with the close votes. All she needed was to edit the question to fix a typo!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out if I put `<xsl:output method="html" />` I no longer output an automatic DOCTYPE. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

There is a comment about this at the end of this page:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/libxml.constants.php

SimpleXML automatically adds a header. There is an option to turn it off when creating an Simple XML object - its the LIBXML_NOXMLDECL but it doesn't work - there is still an open bug about it - see link at the bottom of the page above.

This is what I did in the end:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$root = $doc->createElement('items');
$root = $doc->appendChild($root);
$title = $doc->createElement('title');
$title = $root->appendChild($title);
$text = $doc->createTextNode($item->title);
$text = $title->appendChild($text);
$items[] =  $doc->saveXML($root);
```

Course this doesn't give me a SimpleXml object but at least its xml and doesn't have the header..